# Downgrading Windows 8 to Windows 7 - why 6 partitions?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I bought a computer with Windows 8 and have decided to downgrade to Windows 7. Asus has all the drivers for the model available online, so that shouldn't be a problem.

When I boot into the installation disk and choose to install Windows, it says I'm unable to install on any of the partitions. For all, one of the reasons is that they are GPT and Windows needs to be installed on a disk setup as MBR, using the NTFS file system. For some of the others, it says that one of the reasons Windows cannot be installed on the partition is because it is reserved.

I see the following partitions:

```
Disk 0 Partition 1: SYSTEM, type: System
Disk 0 Partition 2: Recovery, type: OEM (Reserved)
Disk 0 Partition 3, type: MSR (Reserved)
Disk 0 Partition 4: OS, type: Primary
Disk 0 Partition 5: Data, type: Primary
Disk 0 Partition 6: Restore, type: OEM (Reserved)
```

Is there a reason not to format the drive and just create two primary partitions? Is this even necessary?

Comment: GPT drives can be formatted as NTFS.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the 6 partitions are OEM partitions (recovery image). The error occurs, because you haven't booted Win7 in UEFI mode.

You should create a complete backup of your current HDD, use a partition tool, remove all partitions and let the Win7 setup create the partitions, it needs, again.

Comment: OK, that's all I wanted to know - if there's any reason to keep the partitions. I've booted into the Windows 7 installation disk and have the option to format the drive there. Is there a reason to use a partition tool instead of just formatting there?

Comment: @Walkerneo - A partition tool may give you more flexibility in the number and size of the partitions you may want to create. Otherwise, you can let Windows Setup create the partition and then use a tool to resize/repartition later. I don't think it matters.

Comment: Agh, the "format" option wasn't really a format option, it was a "erase contents of partition" option. Now my old Win8 is gone and I can't install Win7 -.- I'm going to try the gparted live cd. Wish me luck

Comment: @Walkerneo: Format only affects a single partition. To clean the disk use diskpart from the command line on the Win7 DVD, or just delete all existing partitions using the GUI. GParted will do the trick too of course. Also be sure to disable Secure Boot from the UEFI settings.

Comment: @Walkerneo that's why I wrote make a complete backup of your Windows 8 so that you can always go back to Win8 if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do, as I've done it hundreds of times so far.

The following steps will clean off all the partitions on the hard drive, and the configuration. You then convert it to MBR format so it uses partitions instead of volumes. You need to do this before the screen asking where to install comes up. If you don't want to lose your data, take a backup first.

1. Start the Windows 7 Setup. Choose your language and click Next.
2. Click <kbd>Install Now</kbd>
3. While waiting, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to bring up the Command Prompt.
4. Type `diskpart` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Type `SELECT DISK 0` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Type `CLEAN` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. Type `CONVERT MBR` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
8. Type `Exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
9. Close the Command Prompt and continue on.

**NOTE**: This will work for the OP only! For other users, when you get to Step 5, type `LIST DISK` and press Enter first! Select your hard drive from the list before you continue on to number 6!

[Source on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725797.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Also -- as a side note from the above comments: If you haven't already, you must change your BIOS setting to enable LEGACY MODE (or CSM on some models). Otherwise the Windows 7 installation will hang and never install.

Comment: The fact the author has 6 partitions means that enabling legacy mode would conflict with his GPT partitions.  There is no reason to enable legacy mode, it will NOT, solve the author's problem